# Python: How to read file from web and make a list from the data?

Tags: python, list, api, url

So I am completely stuck here...I have a url Im supposed to be using and Im trying to read the data and make a list of the earthquakes with a magnitude of 5 or greater. Now I can get my function to print out the data, but its all printed on a couple long lines rather than each earthquake being on their own line. So Im not sure how to append the magnitude value...Here is the function and url:

```
import urllib.request

def readeqi():

    maglist = [] 

    with urllib.request.urlopen('http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/\
        query?format=csv\
        &starttime=1916-02-01\
        &latitude=44.0519\
        &longitude=-123.0867\
        &maxradiuskm=250\
        &minmagnitude=5') as eq:

        line1 = eq.readline()
        line2 = eq.readline()
        line2 = line2.decode()
        line2 = line2.strip().split(',')
        mag = float(line2[4])
    print(mag)
```

Again, I'm trying to take the magnitude values and create a list but I'm not sure how to access just the magnitude value. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

EDIT: Added line1, line2, line2.decode, and mag
  So I figured out how to get the first magnitude. But how can I get all of them above 5?

EDIT2:

Okay so I guess what I really want help with...is how can I strip the data into each of their own lines? Like how can I write a for or a while loop doing what line2.strip() does?

Comment: `AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'request'`
Which version of Python is this?

Comment: Version 3.6 I get no errors when I run mine.

Answer (score 3):

```
import requests
import csv

url = 'http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query'

query = {
    'format': 'csv',
    'starttime': '1916-02-01',
    'latitude': '44.0519',
    'longitude': '-123.0867',
    'maxradiuskm': '250',
    'minmagnitude': '5'
}


response = requests.get(url, params=query)
lines = (line.decode('utf-8') for line in response.iter_lines())
csvreader = csv.DictReader(lines)
```

Now iterate data as you want:

```
>>> g = iter(csvreader)
>>> next(g)['mag']
'6'
>>> next(g)['mag']
'5.9'
>>> next(g)['mag']
'5.9'
>>> next(g)['mag']
'6'
>>> next(g)['mag']
'5.6'
```

Answer (score -1):

Alternate answer, just for kicks: try using Beautiful Soup for scraping data. It has some nice formatting tools.